# DataGridView windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Estou com a seguinte dúvida: Tenho um `Grid` que é composto de várias informações (id, cidade, CEP) e o usuário selecionará varias linhas nesse `Grid`. Eu preciso capturar os códigos selecionados, atribuir esses IDs para uma variável do tipo `int` e gravar no banco de dados. Eu preciso somente dos IDs selecionados para ser salvo no banco.

Renan A minha pergunta é a seguinte como atribuir esses ids  a uma instancia de class porque sto areceber o seguinte erro mesmo depois das sugestões "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto"[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Comment: E qual é a pergunta/dúvida? Você postou somente o que precisa fazer.

Comment: Pelo jeito minha resposta não resolveu o seu problema, tente postar seu código para ficar mais fácil para podemos te ajudar. Aparentemente pela imagem você não está instanciado `fomarsemestre` antes de usá-lo, por isso dá *NullReferenceException*,  ajuste sua pergunta com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade *[SelectedRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows(v=vs.90).aspx)* do seu *DataGridView* e pegar a célula referente ao Id, algo assim:

Em C#

```cs
int id = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow linha in dataGridView.SelectedRows)
{
    // nesse caso o cast só irá funcionar se o tipo de dado
    // que está na coluna for do tipo int, caso contrário
    // utilize Convert.ToInt32, por exemplo
    id = (int) linha.Cells["Id"].Value;

    // faz o que você precisa com o id
}
```

Em VB

```vb
Dim id As Integer
For Each linha As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.SelectedRows
    ' nesse caso o DirectCast só irá funcionar se o tipo de dado
    ' que está na coluna for do tipo Integer, caso contrário
    ' utilize CType, por exemplo
    id = DirectCast(linha.Cells("Id").Value, Integer)

    '  faz o que você precisa com o id
Next
```

Note que para funcionar é necessário que você selecione a linha inteira.